# Unit testing activejdbc code without live database

Tags: unit-testing, junit, activejdbc

Any suggestion on how to test `activejdbc` code without live database? I am unable to follow TDD because at every place it needs a live sql database and I can't mock it. Is having a live sql database for unit testing correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveJDBC reads its metadata from the database on the first access. This means that it requires a database. Typically, you would use a different database for testing than the one you use to run the app. Since ActiveJDBC supports multiple databases you can use H2 In-memory database for your tests.

In any case, what is the purpose of testing ORM classes without a database?

Comment: That's correct. Actually one of my jenkins machine didn't have mysql installed. May be using it with H2 is good option.

Comment: I would recommend using the same database for tests as you do in production to avoid post-deployment surprises:)